# Dart Convert IEEE-11073 32-bit FLOAT to a simple double

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-point, ieee-11073

I don't have much experience working with these low level bytes and numbers, so I've come here for help. I'm connecting to a bluetooth thermometer in my Flutter app, and I get an array of numbers formatted like this according to their documentation. [image] I'm attempting to convert these numbers to a plain temperature double, but can't figure out how. This is the "example" the company gives me. [image] However when I get a reading of 98.5 on the thermometer I get a response as an array of [113, 14, 0, 254]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IEEE-11073 is a commonly used format in medical devices. The table you quoted has everything in it for you to decode the numbers, though might be hard to decipher at first.

Let's take the first example you have: `0xFF00016C`. This is a 32-bit number and the first byte is the exponent, and the last three bytes are the mantissa. Both are encoded in 2s complement representation:

- Exponent, `0xFF`, in 2's complement this is the number `-1`
- Mantissa, `0x00016C`, in 2's complement this is the number `364`

(If you're not quite sure how numbers are encoded in 2's complement, please ask that as a separate question.)

The next thing we do is to make sure it's not a "special" value, as dictated in your table. Since the exponent you have is not `0` (it is `-1`), we know that you're OK. So, no special processing is needed.

Since the value is not special, its numeric value is simply: `mantissa * 10^exponent`. So, we have: `364*10^-1 = 36.4`, as your example shows.

Your second example is similar. The exponent is `0xFE`, and that's the number `-2` in 2's complement. The mantissa is `0x000D97`, which is `3479` in decimal. Again, the exponent isn't 0, so no special processing is needed. So you have: `3479*10^-2 = 34.79`.

You say for the `98.5` value, you get the byte-array `[113, 14, 0, 254]`. Let's see if we can make sense of that. Your byte array, written in hex is:  `[0x71, 0x0E, 0x00, 0xFE]`. I'm guessing you receive these bytes in the "reverse" order, so as a 32-bit hexadecimal this is actually `0xFE000E71`.

We proceed similarly: Exponent is again `-2`, since `0xFE` is how you write `-2` in 2's complement using 8-bits. (See above.) Mantissa is `0xE71` which equals `3697`. So, the number is `3697*10^-2 = 36.97`.

You are claiming that this is actually `98.5`. My best guess is that you are reading it in Fahrenheit, and your device is reporting in Celcius. If you do the math, you'll find that `36.97C = 98.55F`, which is close enough. I'm not sure how you got the `98.5` number, but with devices like this, this outcome seems to be within the precision you can about expect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, thank you! I got the 98.5 number because that was the number that the device was physically showing me after I switched it over to farenheit... but I guess that didn't switch the number it broadcasted

Comment: That is pretty typical, and for good reason! Otherwise the device would also have to send you the unit, and that'd just complicate things. Of course, you should double check with the manufacturer that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I used to convert sfloat16 to double in dart for our flutter app.

```
double sfloat2double(ieee11073) {
    var reservedValues = {
            0x07FE: 'PositiveInfinity',
            0x07FF: 'NaN',
            0x0800: 'NaN',
            0x0801: 'NaN',
            0x0802: 'NegativeInfinity'
        };
    var mantissa = ieee11073 & 0x0FFF;

    
    if (reservedValues.containsKey(mantissa)){
      return 0.0; // basically error
    }
  
    if ((ieee11073 & 0x0800) != 0){
       mantissa =  -((ieee11073 & 0x0FFF) + 1 );
    }else{
      mantissa = (ieee11073 & 0x0FFF);  
    }
    
    var exponent = ieee11073 >> 12;
    if (((ieee11073 >> 12) & 0x8) != 0){
      exponent = -((~(ieee11073 >> 12) & 0x0F) + 1 );
    }else{
      exponent = ((ieee11073 >> 12) & 0x0F); 
    }
    var magnitude = pow(10, exponent);
    return (mantissa * magnitude);  
}
```

Comment: this will decode a 16-bit SFLOAT value, but the question is asking about 32-bit FLOAT values