# Dart/Flutter: Converting BLE characteristic value to double

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, ieee-11073

I have been trying to process data received from a BLE A&D Medical Thermometer (UT-201BLE-A) (Service UUID 0x1809) in my Flutter app.
The characteristic (UUID 0x2A1C, Temperature Measurement) value I retrieve is this array (-Uint8ListView);

```
[6, 112, 1, 0, 255, 229, 7, 2, 12, 10, 56, 34, 2]
```

with the `6` being a flag for the data being in Celcius, and I am only really interested in the following `112, 1, 0, 255`, which corresponds to the temperature (36.8).

They are in `IEEE 11073 32bit float` format.

I have been trying to convert this [Python code I found](https://github.com/gebogebogebo/BLEThermometer/blob/master/src/to_float_from_11073_32bit_float.py) into Dart, but am not having much luck.

I would appreciate any suggestions that could point me in the right direction. So far what I have found regarding this deal with other programming languages I am not familiar with.

**CLARIFICATION -** Despite a similar question being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841331/dart-convert-ieee-11073-32-bit-float-to-a-simple-double), it doesn't directly provide an answer to my problem, thus I asked a new question.

**ANSWER -** Kindly provided by [M. Kotzjan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169331/dart-flutter-converting-ble-characteristic-value-to-double#comment116988117_66169331) in the comments.

Comment: What BLE thermometer are you using? What services and characteristics are you reading? Have a look at this answer on how to use the found UUID to get more informations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66011765/7473793

Comment: It is a A&D Medical Thermometer (UT-201BLE-A), and I'm looking at the characteristic UUID 0x2A1C (for Temperature Measurement).

Comment: Maybe you can found help with this JS snippet, more close to Dart than Python : https://gist.github.com/mold/42935cb1bdda7ae9b3ec72e9d0fa8666
`getInt8` method and `bitwise operators` exist in Dart

Comment: @jamesdlin I tried reading through it but couldn't make sense of some parts. For example, what is the connection between the data 0xFF00016C and a value of 36.4 Celcius.

Comment: @Doubidou Thanks for the suggestion, I am a little confused what a JS `DataView` is and what it's Dart equivalent would be.

Comment: @AndweyChupo Hex FF = -1 in 2's complement, Hex 00016C = 364 in 2's complement. Now calculate 364 * 10^-1 and you got 36.4. In your example you need to reverse the byte order to 255, 0, 1, 112 (in Hex FF000170) and do the same calculation

Comment: @AndweyChupo `printFloatValue(List<int> data, offset) {
  List<int> values = data.getRange(offset, offset+4).toList();
  int mantissa = values[0] | (values[1] << 8) | (values[2] << 16);
  int exponent = (values[3] - 255) - 1;
  print(mantissa * pow(10, exponent));
}` would be the equivalent in dart. Call it using your array and 1 as an offset.

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Thank you very much for the help! Unfortunately I lacked the knowledge about binary numbers, two's complement, etc, so the other similar question went over my head. Now I have something I can read up on.