BLE cannot send the correct temperature measurement char value 0x2A1C
Hardware (BLE server): ESP32-C3-DevKitM-1
Mobile App (BLE client): nRF Connect
Example code: Gatt_Server_Service_Table
IDE: ESP-IDE
I would like to BLE standard Environmental Sensing Service (ESS 0x181A), Temperature Measurement Characteristic (0x2A1C).
How to send the temperature float value such as 25.63℃ in the correct format? If I use uint8_t ess_temperature[] = {0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x00,0x00}; It will show 2563.00℃, but I want to show 25.63℃.
enum{
ESS_SERVICE,

ESS_TEMPERATURE_CHAR,
ESS_TEMPERATURE_VALUE,
ESS_TEMPERATURE_CFG,

ESS_HUMIDITY_SERVICE,
ESS_HUMIDITY_VAL,
ESS_HUMIDITY_CFG,

ESS_IDX_NB,
};

// =============== ESS Service ===============
static const uint16_t GATTS_SERVICE_UUID_ESS                = 0x181A;
static const uint16_t GATTS_CHAR_UUID_ESS_TEMPERATURE       = 0x2A1C;
static const uint16_t GATTS_CHAR_UUID_ESS_HUMIDITY          = 0x2A6F;
//static const uint8_t ess_temperature[2]                   = {0x19, 0x05};     // = 25.5 degC
// static const uint8_t ess_temperature_ccc[2]              = {0x00, 0x00};
//static const uint8_t ess_humidity[2]                          = {0x0B, 0x05};     // = 11.5%
// static const uint8_t ess_humidity_ccc[2]                 = {0x00, 0x00};
uint8_t ess_temperature[5] = {0x00,0x41, 0x33, 0xB9, 0xD7};
static const uint16_t ess_humidity = 3556;     // nRF Connect App will divide this value by 100. For example, if we use 3654, App will show 36.54% humidity



static const esp_gatts_attr_db_t ess_gatt_db[ESS_IDX_NB] =
{
    [ESS_SERVICE]        =
    {{ESP_GATT_AUTO_RSP}, {ESP_UUID_LEN_16, (uint8_t *)&primary_service_uuid, ESP_GATT_PERM_READ,
    sizeof(uint16_t), sizeof(GATTS_SERVICE_UUID_ESS), (uint8_t *)&GATTS_SERVICE_UUID_ESS}},

    // Temperature -------------------------------------------------
    [ESS_TEMPERATURE_CHAR]     =
    {{ESP_GATT_AUTO_RSP}, {ESP_UUID_LEN_16, (uint8_t *)&character_declaration_uuid, ESP_GATT_PERM_READ,
    CHAR_DECLARATION_SIZE, CHAR_DECLARATION_SIZE, (uint8_t *)&char_prop_read}},

    [ESS_TEMPERATURE_VALUE] =
    {{ESP_GATT_AUTO_RSP}, {ESP_UUID_LEN_16, (uint8_t *)&GATTS_CHAR_UUID_ESS_TEMPERATURE, ESP_GATT_PERM_READ,
    GATTS_DEMO_CHAR_VAL_LEN_MAX, sizeof(ess_temperature), (uint8_t *)&ess_temperature}},

    [ESS_TEMPERATURE_CFG]  =
    {{ESP_GATT_AUTO_RSP}, {ESP_UUID_LEN_16, (uint8_t *)&character_client_config_uuid, ESP_GATT_PERM_READ | ESP_GATT_PERM_WRITE,
    sizeof(uint16_t), sizeof(cccd_disable_notify_indicate), (uint8_t *)cccd_disable_notify_indicate}},

    // Humidity -------------------------------------------
    [ESS_HUMIDITY_SERVICE]      =
    {{ESP_GATT_AUTO_RSP}, {ESP_UUID_LEN_16, (uint8_t *)&character_declaration_uuid, ESP_GATT_PERM_READ,
    CHAR_DECLARATION_SIZE, CHAR_DECLARATION_SIZE, (uint8_t *)&char_prop_read}},

    [ESS_HUMIDITY_VAL]  =
    {{ESP_GATT_AUTO_RSP}, {ESP_UUID_LEN_16, (uint8_t *)&GATTS_CHAR_UUID_ESS_HUMIDITY, ESP_GATT_PERM_READ,
    GATTS_DEMO_CHAR_VAL_LEN_MAX, sizeof(ess_humidity), (uint8_t *)&ess_humidity}},

    [ESS_HUMIDITY_CFG]  =
    {{ESP_GATT_AUTO_RSP}, {ESP_UUID_LEN_16, (uint8_t *)&character_client_config_uuid, ESP_GATT_PERM_READ | ESP_GATT_PERM_WRITE,
    sizeof(uint16_t), sizeof(cccd_disable_notify_indicate), (uint8_t *)cccd_disable_notify_indicate}},
};



0x03, 0x0A is a hint, that you are transmitting an integer and not a float value. What format does your client expect from your server? Mind that for transmitting a float, you need a float variable (4 Byte usually). And mind potential differences in byte ordering between ESP and your host device software.

According to the GATT Specification Supplement, Chap. 3.222 Temperature Measurement, the data type is medfloat32, which is defined in IEEE 11073-20601.
Here is a description of how to convert a float value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60843099/8124605
For example, a value of 25.63℃ can be coded as
Exponent: 0xFE     -> -2
Mantissa: 0x000A03 -> 2563
uint8_t ess_temperature[] = { 0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x00, 0xFE };

